# How to load selected beans from external library in micronaut

Tags: import, external, micronaut

I'm used to creating custom Spring Boot based libraries with `a number of different beans` per library. A target Spring Boot app then would use `@Import` to make a `subset` of those Beans available w/out importing all of the beans from an external library. An external library would also include spring integration tests (i.e. `@SpringBootTest`).

I'm trying to replicate this functionality in Micronaut. I've created an external library using 'io.micronaut.library' gradle plugin. It also contains some micronaut integration tests (i.e. `@MicronautTest`).

Per https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#beanImport I expected none of the beans to be imported by default. However, I've noticed that a class annotated with `@Singleton` was imported by default. I suspect this is due to its inclusion in the `META-INF/services/io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference` within the library jar. If I remove `META-INF/services/io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference` from the jar manually then none of the beans are imported by default and I can use explicit `@Import` to import what is needed.

The package of the library is `com.some.micronaut.http` while application package is `com.some.somethingelse` so the namespaces do not match. Both the library and the application are written in Kotlin.

Is there a way to control which beans are imported from an external library? Or can I control which bean references are included in `META-INF/services/io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference`?

Here is a relevant `build.gradle` portion from the external library:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id 'io.micronaut.library' version "3.1.1"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")

    //test
    testImplementation 'io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params'

    //wiremock for http client tests
    testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.32.0'
}
```

I'm flexible about usage of `io.micronaut.library` plugin but I do need to be able to run `@MicronautTest` as part of the library build.

Comment: "Per https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#beanImport I expected none of the beans to be imported by default. However, I've noticed that a class annotated with @Singleton was imported by default." - Is it the case that the `@Singleton` beans that surprised you when they were loaded were compiled with the Micronaut injection annotation processors in play?  If yes, you don't need to use the bean import capabilities.

Comment: I need to pick and choose in the target app which beans to import. I have verified that all classes included in `META-INF/services/io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference` will be imported implicitly. I need a way to exclude beans from `META-INF/services/io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference` or exclude that file from the library jar. I could probably do it manually in gradle after jar is created but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to conditionally load beans by package or do you need to opt beans in/out within packages?

Comment: Ideally, I would like none of the beans imported by default and then use @Import to explicitly import what I want.

Comment: "Ideally, I would like none of the beans imported by default and then use @Import to explicitly import what I want." - I don't know of a way to do that if the service descriptor is already in the .jar.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've removed `META-INF/services/io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference` from the library jar explicitly in my build.gradle:

```
jar {
    exclude('META-INF/services/io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference')
}
```

and then used `@Import` in my application to explicitly import the desired components. I've also submitted an enhancement [request](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/7077).

Comment: FYI... If you have control over the compilation of those beans, if you omit the Micronaut annotation processors from their build, the descriptor won't be created to begin with.