# How to make Micronaut create Beans from a custom Library?

Tags: micronaut

I tried the steps as described in the following [article](https://kreuzwerker.de/post/modularizing-with-micronaut-framework)

Or same as in this GitHub [post](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1101)

It didn't work for me.

I also read this approach: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71472203/how-to-load-selected-beans-from-external-library-in-micronaut) But this is not what I am searching for

How can I customize my Library in a way, to make Micronaut capable of creating and injecting its beans directly in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I customize my Library in a way, to make Micronaut capable of
> creating and injecting its beans directly in my project?

If you want to customize the library, compile it with a dependency on the appropriate compile time annotation processors and then consume that .jar in your Micronaut app the same way you would any other .jar.  [plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.micronaut.library](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.micronaut.library) is helpful for that if you are using Gradle.

If you are consuming a library for which you can't do that, the `@Factory` annotation is specifically for this.

```
@Factory
class MyFactory {

    @Singleton
    SomeLibraryType someMethod() {
        // this could contain any appropriate
        // initialization code...
        return new SomeLibraryType();
    }
}
```

See [docs.micronaut.io/3.4.2/guide/#factories](https://docs.micronaut.io/3.4.2/guide/#factories).