# Bean Injection Issue from dependency jar for micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

I have a common modules that defines caffiene-cache for us like

```
@Factory
public class CaffeineCacheFactory {

    @Value("${cache.max.size}")
    private long maximumSize;

    @Value("${cache.duration.hours}")
    private long durationInHours;

    @Bean
    @Named("caffeine-cache")
    public Cache<String, Object> entitlementCache() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(maximumSize)
                .expireAfterWrite(durationInHours, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .build();
    }
}
```

we have built this common module as a jar and are using it in another project as dependency. The problem is in the main code this bean is not found and could not be intialized. I am not sure what I am missing here.

I have micronaut-inject-java in annotation processor. The only difference is common module is built on 3.8.0 but main module is on micronaut 4.1.3

```
@Singleton
public class CacheService {
    final Cache<String, String> cache;

    public CacheService(Cache<String, String> cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71956289/how-to-make-micronaut-create-beans-from-a-custom-library)

Comment: @SolermanKaplon I am using maven so that plugin isn't available to download but otherwise from code perspective implemented the same way as mentioned